# SSL Certificate: A specified logon session does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a method which will create a certificate, store it to Certificate store and bind it to a port.
Here it is the method:

```
private static void CreateStoreAndBindCertificate(string a_IpAddress, string a_IpPort)
        {
            Guid _AppId = Guid.Parse("b30f5be6-2920-4fa1-b0a6-5a56b63051bc");

            var _RootCert = new RootCertificateContainer("CN=MyApp Root CA", 1024);
            var _ServerCert = new ServerCertificateContainer("CN=MyAppApi", _RootCert, 1024);

            //Here the Certificate will be created and then store
            string _pathRootCertCER = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "root-cert.cer");
            string _pathServerCerPFX = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "server-cert.pfx");

            _RootCert.X509Certificate.PrivateKey = null;
            File.WriteAllBytes(
                _pathRootCertCER,
                _RootCert.X509Certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert)
            );

            var _ServerCertPFX = new PFX(_ServerCert.X509Certificate);
            File.WriteAllBytes(_pathServerCerPFX, _ServerCertPFX.GeneratePfxFile());

            Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -p -importPFX \"{0}\"", _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();

            try
            {
                ICertificateBindingConfiguration config = new CertificateBindingConfiguration();
                var _IpPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(a_IpAddress), Convert.ToInt32(a_IpPort));
                var certificateThumbprint = _ServerCert.X509Certificate.Thumbprint.ToLower();
                if (config.Query(_IpPort).Length > 0)
                    config.Delete(_IpPort);
                config.Bind(new CertificateBinding(certificateThumbprint, StoreName.My, _IpPort, _AppId));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When i execute this method with parameters: `CreateStoreAndBindCertificate("127.0.0.1", "9001")`, i get this error: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been termintaed.`
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a certificate to be bind in the port i want i need to create the .pfx certificate using a password. So i will make same small changes:

```
const string passwordPFX = "MyPassword";
```

should be added in the beginning of the Method. Change:

```
var _ServerCertPFX = new PFX(_serverCert.X509Certificate);
```

to

```
var _ServerCertPFX = new PFX(_serverCert.X509Certificate, passwordPFX);
```

Change:

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -p  -importPFX \"{0}\"", _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```

to:

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -p {0} -importPFX \"{1}\"", passwordPFX, _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```

**Another possible solution could be that you do not use password at all so you have to remove `-p` from `ProcessStartInfo` `Arguments`.** It will look like below:

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -importPFX \"{0}\"",  _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```